# Facebook iOS SDK - FWWebDialogs not rendering message

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK in an iOS app.  I'm logging in fine, pulling in friends lists, etc.

I've added code to send a request:

```
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:session
 message:@"Message"
 title:@"Title"
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     // view cleanup here
 }];
```

The session is the `FBSession` stored in the class handling login.  The params are `suggestions`, an array of friends to include.  The issue described below occurs equally if params is nil (in which case the list shows all friends).

When I call the dialog, this is what appears:

[image: Request screenshot]

Note that the "Message" text is missing, as is the entire Message block shown on the various Facebook documentation pages such as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/requests/.

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.7.1, the latest version as of this posting.  The screenshot above is from the Simulator using a Facebook Test User account.  The same issues occur on a device using a "real" Facebook account.

Comment: I have the same problem with sdk 3.7.1

Comment: and I have the same problem with sdk 3.8! any solution?

Comment: likewise I see this, I guess the intention when not specifying the to parameter is to provide more space for the list of friends to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is "By Design"!! :(

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/605575982818621

Comment: Thanks for finding that comment/response.  At least tells me it's intentionally busted... :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same issue.  It appears to be a very recent development, as previously the dialog did show the message preview.  I also noticed that the dialog does show the message preview if I specify the 'to' parameter; the message preview is missing only if I omit the 'to' parameter so that the dialog shows all the user's friends.  Unfortunately I don't have a solution, but I wanted to share these additional observations if it helps get closer to the solution.

- Andrew

Comment: Specifying a @"to" parameter works for me as well, as long as the @"to" is in my friends or a player of the game (this seems to be a requirement of message sending in any case).