# Facebook iOS app requests not launching locally built app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

We have a live game on the iOS app store, and I'm currently adding some Facebook integration. I'm trying to test deep linking with app requests, but the recipient side won't launch my locally built app; instead, it goes to the app's page on the app store. What do I need to change (FB app settings? Xcode build settings?) to get this to work? I can only assume it's possible...

**EDIT**: should mention I'm using the latest SDK (3.7.1), building against iOS 6.1.

**EDIT 2**: short of taking a screenshot and blacking a bunch of stuff out, I'll describe how my FB app config is set up:

In `Settings -> Basic`, I only have data filled out of `Native iOS App`, which includes the `Bundle ID`
(that matches the ID Xcode is building the app with), `iPhone/iPad App Store ID` (matches the live app in the store), `Facebook Login` and `Deep Linking` are both enabled, and `URL Scheme Suffix` is empty. The app is also in `Sandbox Mode`. In `Settings -> Permissions`, I have `publish_actions` (in `User & Friend Permissions`) and `publish_stream` (in `Extended Permissions`). I think everything else is vanilla.

In the project plist, the `Bundle identifier` is the same as described in the FB app settings. The only possible discrepancy is the `FacebookAppID` in the plist does not match this particular Facebook test app that I'm working with... I don't think that should matter but it's worth mentioning.

As far as actually sending the request, code is as follows:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:message
                                                title:nil
                                           parameters:nil
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  // handle response
                                              }];
```

I do this earlier on also, to decide which FB app to connect to:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

#if GO_TO_TEST_APP
    NSString *fbAppId = [dict objectForKey:@"TestFacebookAppID"];
#else
    NSString *fbAppId = [dict objectForKey:@"FacebookAppID"];
#endif

    NSAssert(fbAppId, @"Failed to get Facebook app id from plist file!");

    [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:fbAppId];
```

Again, the request does get sent correctly (although I am seeing the same problem as is being seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501290/facebook-ios-sdk-fwwebdialogs-not-rendering-message) when the dialog pops up), and I can see the request on the recipient's Facebook acct; it's just the redirect doesn't pick up on the fact that I have the app already installed on the device (albeit built locally with Xcode).

Comment: I'm probably not alone in being unsure what's being asked. Does the mechanism you're attempting to implement work by declaring support for the fb<your app id> URL scheme and catch accesses to that, with Facebook having some Javascript fallback that redirects to the app store if the device fails to respond to that call?

Comment: Why don't you show us some code/config?

Comment: Added more info... hope that helps!

Comment: Just made an observation... with the app store app actually downloaded, the app request still opens the app store instead of launching the app (and the app store button says `OPEN`)... is that intended behavior?

Comment: I have the answer actually, @Tommy was right, just wasn't aware of that mechanism (thought it would have keyed off the bundle id... guess not). I can't post my answer for 3 hours though because I'm a n00b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tommy above is right; I needed to adjust `URL types -> Item 0 -> URL Schemes` in my `Info.plist` file to include the FB scheme for the new test app I'm trying to connect to (in the form of `fb<Facebook App ID>`. I already have the one for the live FB app; I just didn't realize that configuration step existed.